# ROS Subscriber and Publisher node

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS community,

I want to implement a ROS node that is both subscriber and publisher. The idea is that each time the subscribed topic changes, the node will publish to another topic. The node takes a detection command and gives a door command controlling a USB latch.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
import serial

#Declaring USB port related to relay
relayport = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyUSB0",
baudrate = 9600,
bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
timeout = 1,
writeTimeout = 2)

#Declaring open and close commands in bytes used to control relay
open_cmd = b'\xA0\x01\x01\xA2'
close_cmd = b'\xA0\x01\x00\xA1'

door_state = ''

def Lock_callback(detection): #Callback function to be used when receiving detection topic data
    global door_state
    rospy.loginfo("Command is %s", detection.data)
    if detection.data == 'SH' or detection.data == 'MH' : #Close relay (ON) in Short High and Medium High states to lock door
        relayport.write(close_cmd)
        door_state = 'closed'
        rospy.loginfo("door_state %s", door_state)
    else : #Open relay (OFF) in other detection states
        relayport.write(open_cmd)
        door_state = 'opened'
        rospy.loginfo("door_state %s", door_state)

def Lock_decision(): #Lock decision function to subscribe to detection state topic and publish Lock topic
    Lock_pub = rospy.Publisher('/doorcmd', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('Latch_decision', anonymous=True) #Create ROS node for relay
    Lock_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/detection', String, Lock_callback) #Subscribe node to relay command topic
    Lock_pub.publish(door_state)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        Lock_decision()
```

The Lock_pub.publish only gives one value at the start and stops which is not what I want. I want to publish the /doorcmd topic everytime it is changed by the /detection topic.
Any clues on how to do that ? What is the problem in my code ?

Thanks and regards.
Lilia.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416057/ros-subscriber-and-publisher-node/) by [Lilipop](https://answers.ros.org/users/149103/lilipop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2023-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

The problem with your code is that you are actually calling `Lock_pub.publish()` once. This triggers the callback once. Then, the interpreter reaches `rospy.spin()` which keeps your program from stopping. When the callback receives a new detection, then `door_state` changes, but `Lock_pub.publish()` is not called anymore (you are "stuck" at `rospy.spin()`).

To achieve the behavior you want, you could use a class as follows:

```
class LatchDecision():
    def __init__(self):
        #Declaring USB port related to relay
        self.relayport = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyUSB0",
            baudrate = 9600,
            bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS, 
            parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
            timeout = 1,
            writeTimeout = 2)

        #Declaring open and close commands in bytes used to control relay
        self.OPEN_CMD = b'\xA0\x01\x01\xA2'
        self.CLOSE_CMD = b'\xA0\x01\x00\xA1'

        # Create the publisher and the subscriber
        self.Lock_pub = rospy.Publisher('/doorcmd', String, queue_size=10)
        self.Lock_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/detection', String, self.Lock_callback)

    def Lock_callback(self, detection):
        door_state
        rospy.loginfo("Command is %s", detection.data)
        if detection.data == 'SH' or detection.data == 'MH': 
            self.relayport.write(self.CLOSE_CMD)
            door_state = 'closed'
        else :        
            self.relayport.write(self.OPEN_CMD)
            door_state = 'opened'
        
        rospy.loginfo("door_state %s", door_state)
        self.Lock_pub.publish(door_state)


if __name__ == "__main__":
        rospy.init_node('Latch_decision', anonymous=True)
        ld = LatchDecision()
        rospy.spin()
```

In this way, every time you have a new detection, you also publish a message on `/doorcmd`.

**Note.** I have made `OPEN/CLOSE_CMD` as they are constants. It is a good practice as it improves readability, but it does not affect the execution at all.

---

Originally posted by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) with karma: 221 on 2023-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lilipop](https://answers.ros.org/users/149103/lilipop/) on 2023-06-01**:
Hi, I thought that with each function call the publisher would execute too. Your explanation is very clear, I just tested your changes and it works perfectly.

Thank you so much for the help !

Lilia.

**Comment by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) on 2023-06-01**:
Great!

If it actually solved your problem, would you mind marking the answer as *correct*?

Thanks!